# What Happens When You Have Multiple Unarmed Strike Dice?

Tags: dnd-5e, dice, unarmed-combat

So, while flipping through the PHB, I've noticed that in 5th edition, multiple abilities can give you a buff on your unarmed strike, such as a monk's Martial Arts ability, the Tavern Brawler feat or an Aarakockra's claws.

If I were to make a monk with the Way of the Drunken Warrior archetype and give him the Tavern Brawler feat, is the d4 for unarmed strike from the feat rendered useless?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: ok, thank you. yes, I did notice questions like it before, I just wasn't sure because it felt wasteful to just get rid of an extra ability like that. I dunno, maybe I could mess around with a bit of homebrew for it.